# LWC issue with replacing first invalid character

Tags: lightning-web-components, regular-expressions

In my LWC, I have a text input where I need to prevent the user from entering anything besides a number or a decimal point.  The Javascript function I'm using does replace the invalid characters with a null string.  However, if the user enters an initial minus sign, that character isn't removed until the user enters a second character.

Is there a way to immediately replace that initial minus sign immediately after it is typed?

[image]

[image]

Following is the code:

payment2.html

```html
<template>
    
    <div class="slds-var-p-around_large slds-var-m-around_medium" style="width: 200px; background: #fff;">

        <lightning-input 
            type="number" 
            name="anotherAmount" 
            label="Another Amount" 
            variant="standard" 
            value={anotherAmount} 
            min="1"
            onchange={handleAnotherAmountChange}
            formatter="currency"
            >
        </lightning-input>

    </div>

</template>
```

payment2.js

```js
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

    const anotherAmountStripInvalidChars = value => {
        let returnValue = value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g,'');
        return returnValue;
    }

    export default class Payment2 extends LightningElement {

    anotherAmount;

    handleAnotherAmountChange(event) {
        const value = event.detail.value;

        const xform = anotherAmountStripInvalidChars(value);
        console.log('xform:', xform);

        this.anotherAmount = xform;
    }

}
```

A live example:  https://webcomponents.dev/edit/lCXRIYqj4Iwt88qOZzml/src/app.css?p=stories

GitHub repo:  https://github.com/mikesobczak/LWC-Invalid-Chars-Issue

Comment: I'm curious as to why I was down-voted?  I got an awesome response to this question, so the down-vote seems unfair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter out the hyphen in a keydown event handler.

```
<lightning-input type="number" name="anotherAmount" label="Another Amount" variant="standard" value={anotherAmount}
    min="1" onkeydown={checkKey} onchange={handleAnotherAmountChange} formatter="currency">
</lightning-input>
```

---

```
checkKey(event) {
    if(event.key.length === 1 && !event.key.match(/[0-9\.]/)) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/pCpuYKdSyPOqZeWFSCLM/src/app.js?p=stories).

Comment: Brilliant!  Let me know if you have a digital tip jar, so I can buy you a beer!

Comment: @MichaelSobczak You can find one on venmo under this moniker, or you can use the link on my profile. Tips are always appreciated .